# CloudPebble PebbleJS Emulator hanging

Tags: pebble-sdk

I'm trying to emulate an app that works on my pebble, using PebbleJS. When I install it on the emulator, it hangs on "Preparing to install app…"

I can't see any logs to see where or why it hung.

Comment: Apparently Basalt emulator is having issues, try using Aplite meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

Try a different browser,refreshing browser or clicking on the cog and selecting shut down and then installing on emulator, Try to use "console.log()" as much as you can to see how far your code goes before it hangs